# Spark dataframe - Group strings by position in array

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Using Spark 1.6 on scala, how do I group each characters in the code column by position by key? First strings together, second characters together etc...

```
val someDF = Seq(
    (123, "0000"), 
    (123, "X000"),
    (123, "C111"),
    (124, "0000"),
    (124, "0000"),
    (124, "C200")).toDF("key", "code")

someDF.show()
+---+----+
|key|code|
+---+----+
|123|0000|
|123|X000|
|123|C111|
|124|0000|
|124|0000|
|124|C200|
+---+----+



val df = someDF.select($"key", split($"code","").as("code_split"))

df.show()
+---+--------------+
|key|    code_split|
+---+--------------+
|123|[0, 0, 0, 0, ]|
|123|[X, 0, 0, 0, ]|
|123|[C, 1, 1, 1, ]|
|124|[0, 0, 0, 0, ]|
|124|[0, 0, 0, 0, ]|
|124|[C, 2, 0, 0, ]|
+---+--------------+
```

Using collect_list, I can do it for one column at a time. How can I do it for all the combination without looping?

```
df
.select($"id",
    $"code_split"(0).as("m1"),  
    $"code_split"(1).as("m2"),
    $"code_split"(2).as("m3"),
    $"code_split"(3).as("m4")
    )
.groupBy($"id").agg(
    collect_list($"m1"), 
    collect_list($"m2"),
    collect_list($"m3"),
    collect_list($"m4")
    )
.show()

+---+----------------+----------------+----------------+----------------+
| id|collect_list(m1)|collect_list(m2)|collect_list(m3)|collect_list(m4)|
+---+----------------+----------------+----------------+----------------+
|123|       [0, X, C]|       [0, 0, 1]|       [0, 0, 1]|       [0, 0, 1]|
|124|       [0, 0, C]|       [0, 0, 1]|       [0, 0, 0]|       [0, 0, 0]|
+---+----------------+----------------+----------------+----------------+
```

Is there a way to get to the same result without repeating the collect_list in agg? If I have 60 instances, I don't want to copy-paste that 60 times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the `code` column will have to be split in order to achieve the result, but into columns per character, rather than into arrays. This will facilitate the further grouping of characters.

This split can be done with the following:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

val originalDf: DataFrame = ...

// split function: returns a new dataframe with column "code{i}"
// containing the character at index "i" from "code" column 
private def splitCodeColumn(df: DataFrame, i: Int): DataFrame = {
  df.withColumn("code" + i, substring(originalDf("code"), i, 1))
}

// number of columns to split code in
val nbSplitColumns = "0000".length

val codeColumnSplitDf = 
  (1 to nbSplitColumns).foldLeft(originalDf){ case(df, i) => splitCodeColumn(df, i)}.drop("code")

// register it in order to use with Spark SQL
val splitTempViewName = "code_split"
codeColumnSplitDf.registerTempTable(splitTempViewName)
```

Now `codeColumnSplitDf` contains:

```
+---+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|key|code1|code2|code3|code4|
+---+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|123|    0|    0|    0|    0|
|123|    X|    0|    0|    0|
|123|    C|    1|    1|    1|
|124|    0|    0|    0|    0|
|124|    0|    0|    0|    0|
|124|    C|    2|    0|    0|
+---+-----+-----+-----+-----+
```

We'll use `collect_list` function to aggregate the characters grouped by `key`:

```
// collect_list calls to insert into SQL
val aggregateSelections = (1 to nbSplitColumns).map(i => s"collect_list(code$i) as code_$i").mkString(", ")

val sqlCtx: SQLContext = ...

// DataFrames with expected results
val resultDf = sqlCtx.sql(s"SELECT key, $aggregateSelections FROM $splitTempViewName GROUP BY key")
```

`resultDf` contains:

```
+---+---------+---------+---------+---------+
|key|   code_1|   code_2|   code_3|   code_4|
+---+---------+---------+---------+---------+
|123|[0, X, C]|[0, 0, 1]|[0, 0, 1]|[0, 0, 1]|
|124|[0, 0, C]|[0, 0, 2]|[0, 0, 0]|[0, 0, 0]|
+---+---------+---------+---------+---------+
```

*Update*

To avoid repeating elements in `select` and `agg`:

```
val codeSplitColumns =
  Seq(col("id")) ++ (0 until nbSplitColumns).map(i => col("code_split")(i).as("m" + i))

val aggregations =
  (0 until nbSplitColumns).map(i => collect_list(col("m" + i)))

df.select(codeSplitColumns:_*)
  .groupBy(col("id"))
  .agg(aggregations.head, aggregations.tail:_*)
```

Answer (score 0):

> > Is there a way to get to the same result without repeating the collect_list in agg?

Yes, definitely there are multiple ways to use **collect_list only once**. I am going to show you using `udf` function

**the udf function**

```
def combineUdf = udf((strs: Seq[String])=> {
  val length = strs(0).length
  val groupLength = strs.length
  val result = for(i <- 0 until length; arr <- strs)yield arr(i).toString
  result.grouped(groupLength).map(_.toArray).toArray
})
```

The `combineUdf` function *takes the collected list of strings* (as you are going to use only one `collect_list` function) and then *parse the array* to give you the required output but in `Array` form as `Array[Array[String]]`

Just call the `udf` and `select` all the necessary columns as

```
someDF.groupBy("key").agg(combineUdf(collect_list("code")).as("value"))
    .select(col("key") +: (0 to 3).map(x => col("value")(x).as("value_"+x)): _*)
    .show(false)
```

where `(0 to 3)` can be varied according to your *final column necessity*

which should give you *your desired output* as

```
+---+---------+---------+---------+---------+
|key|value_0  |value_1  |value_2  |value_3  |
+---+---------+---------+---------+---------+
|123|[0, X, C]|[0, 0, 1]|[0, 0, 1]|[0, 0, 1]|
|124|[0, 0, C]|[0, 0, 2]|[0, 0, 0]|[0, 0, 0]|
+---+---------+---------+---------+---------+
```

I hope the answer is helpful